# RestTemplate post in json,getBody is null

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I meet a situation like this:I need to call an external interface,it works with the first way.But now,I need to use the second way,sadly it didn't work.

### first way

```
try {
        String url = "http://domain/service";
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        List nvps = new ArrayList();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsoncommond", jsoncommond));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String APIresult = "";
        if (entity != null) {
            APIresult = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "utf-8");
        }
        System.out.println("==="+ APIresult);
        EntityUtils.consume((org.apache.http.HttpEntity) entity);
        response.close();
        response.close();
        httpclient.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

### second way

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsoncommond,headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,entity,String.class);

    System.out.println("-----"+response+"\n----=-"+response.getBody());
```

The result like this,`response.getBody()` is null

```
**-----<200 OK,{Server=[], Content-Type=[text;html;charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[Wed, 28 Jun 2017 05:26:22 GMT]}>
----=-null**
```

---

jsoncommond is a json string like this:

```
    {
      "request": {
        "aPPID": "aa",
        "aPPKEY": "bb"
      },
      "data": {
        "address": "x",
        "city": "y",
        "country": "z"
      }
    }
```

Why is that? Please hele me!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the WS expects `jsoncommond` parameter but you send it as a body.

Try the code below instead.

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> variables = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
variables.put("jsoncommond", Collections.singletonList(convertToJSON(jsoncommond)));

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(variables, headers);
...
```

UPDATE:

```
private String convertToJSON(Object obj) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        if (obj == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (obj instanceof String) {
            return (String) obj;
        }
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new SOAControllerInvocationException("Cannot serialize to JSON " + obj, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the `convertToJSON`?This's my jsoncommondp[

Comment: it's just something which converts the value to json string/ Actually you can try to use both - the object directly and JSON String representation of the object. Added my function

Comment: This's my jsoncommond variable like:`String jsoncommond ="{"
                +"\"request\":{"
                +" \"aPPID\":\"aaa\","
                +" \"aPPKEY\":\"bbb\""            
                +" },"
                +"\"data\":{"
                +" \"address\":\"xx\","
                +" \"city\":\"yy\","
                +" \"country\":\"zz\""                
                +" }"
                +" }";` .The jsoncommond is not a Object.So,Is this necessary to use your `convertToJSON`?

Comment: You still can use the function. If the argument is String it's returned as is OR of course you can skip the convert logic

Comment: Ok,I see.I have a try.Thank you very much.